# Fill form with Javascript code in browsers addressbar

Tags: javascript, com

I want to ease the users experience on a external partner website by giving him a copy/paste line to prefill the form with the data from our database.

TASK: **Fill form with javascript in Browsers ADRESS BAR (Firefox/chrome mandatory)**

There is a COM (MS) extension and i can't find any working example under Firefox or generic to work.

i remember putting this in address bar once worked:

```
javascript: document.getElementById('name').value = "barnaba"; void 0
```

Any working and smoother approach needed :)

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok

there is a code to open a command prompt where you can submit pure Javascript

```
javascript:var a=prompt();var f=Function(a);f()
```

To fill a form it can be done like this:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByName('nechama')[0].value="It's a me"; void 0;
```

neat, isn't it

Btw, COM extension only applys to MS InternetExplorer. The provided code example applys to any major Browser.